# Wrong size in bytes being displayed using BytesIO in Django

Tags: python, django, byte

I am trying to validate images before they are uploaded to the database using django , but cant seem to get accurate size of images no matter what I do

view.py:

```
def upload_image(request):                       #used to upload images in document_upload
    c = main.objects.get(username = request.session['username'])
    unq_id = c.unq_id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        images = request.FILES.getlist('image')
        name = request.POST['name']
        for x in images:
            img = Image.open(x)
            img_file = BytesIO()
            img.save(img_file, 'jpeg')
            image_file_size = img.tell()

            if image_file_size > 150 * 1024:
                print(image_file_size)
                failure = "image needs to be lesser dimenstion than 150kb"
                return render(request, 'Main/document_upload.html', {'failure':failure})
            else:
                print(image_file_size)
                fs = FileSystemStorage()
                filename = fs.save(x.name, x)
                Doc1 = Doc(user_id = unq_id, upload = x, name = name)
                Doc1.save()
                success = "You have successfully added documents, proceed to 'My documents' to see your documents"
    return render(request, 'Main/document_upload.html', {'success':success})
```

While printing `print(image_file_size)` I seem to be getting a much lesser value , than the size shown in it's properties

example `print(image_file_size)` shows `1295` while in reality the size is `8537`

How do I solve this ? thank you

Comment: Try to use `.seek(0, 2)` before calling `.tell()`.

Answer (score 0):

ok so the answer was quite simple , turns out reading the documentation solves everything and the discord community is extremely helpful too especially a guy name @zylon

so it turns out that file object has a method called size, which gives the accurate value:

ie `x.size` would give you the accurate file size( same as shown in properties)

PS: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/files/file/ this will help